# Grouping more than 4 fields in report. Any workaround?

Tags: reporting

I have few fields on a object. In the report i would like to group using 7 fields so that i can see how data is distributed across multiple subgroups.

Summary report has limited grouping to 3 and matrix has limited it to 4. is there any workaround to group using multiple fields (more than 4)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Other than using something else for reporting? Einstein Analytics, Tableau and  others will give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reports only give you that level of granularity. You can get a nice layout if you use the GROUP BY function in SOQL, but keep in mind you won't see individual records. To do this, simply go to the Developer Console, go the query tab, and type in a query like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7
FROM Object1
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5, Field6, Field7
```

This works for up to 32 distinct fields, and may include parent fields.